# PHP exporting values from database, comma separated, in a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, csv

The tables look like this:

```
virtuemart_customfield_id___|___virtuemart_product_id___|____custom_value___
                        1   |                   4346    |           45
                        2   |                   4346    |           46
                        3   |                   4347    |           45
```

This function is working properly as is.

```
function getSizes($product_id){
    global $mainframe;
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `#__virtuemart_product_customfields` WHERE `virtuemart_product_id` ='.$product_id.'';
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $result=$db->loadObjectList();
    return $result;
}
```

And this is the code that will call the fuction and get the data from the database, and try to separate the values I need with commas.

```
$records = $this->getSizes($product_id);
$product_size = '';
foreach ($records as $value){
    $size = $value->custom_value;
    if ($product_size == '') {
        $product_size .= $size;
    } else {
        $product_size .= ", " .$size;
}
```

The problem seems to be inside this piece of code somewhere, but I have no idea where...
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What s failing ? What result do you get ?

Comment: I don't get any result, that's my problem. Because I don't have experience with php, I don't know how to debug it.
Specifically, that is a component in Joomla, and when its failing, i simply get a blank page.

Comment: Did you check your SQL query works by outpouting it and run it on a shell ?

Comment: Yes the query returns the prefered results on the phpmyadmin backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way (firts assign to $size without concatenation)

```
$records = $this->getSizes($product_id);
$product_size = '';
foreach ($records as $value){
   $size = $value->custom_value;
   if ($product_size == '') {
       $product_size = $size;
   } else {
       $product_size .= ", " .$size;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. just found the solution.. the if is not closing.. the last } belongs to the else.

Comment: Also your version is more logical, that's why approved it as an answer!

Comment: I have update the answer with the `}` for close the foreach .  thanks